# Spring Path variable binding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller method(created for test purpose) as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/sample/{theme:red|green")
public String getThemeTest(TestRequestBean requestBean, @PathVariable String theme, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    .......... some processing............
    return viewname;
}
```

Here is my TestRequestBean.java

```
public class TestRequestBean {

    private String theme;

    public String getTheme() {
        return this.theme;
    }

    public void setTheme(String theme) {
        this.theme = theme;
    }

}
```

We use Spring 3.2.4 release. As per my understanding, `@PathVariable` should get bound to `Model objects`, which in my case, theme should get bound to `TestRequestBean.theme` variable. I have the setter and getters in the POJO. If I do a simple boot in spring 4.x and this binding works fine, whereas in 3.2.4 it is not working. Any idea if this was added after specific release?

Comment: AFAIK there will be no binding for path variables, they will only be available in the `Model` under their specific name, in this case `theme`. For binding only request parameters are used, this might have changed but I'm not aware of those changes.

Comment: It does bind in spring 4.x (spring-boot) when i tried. Some how i could not get it working in 3.2.x and it is a huge application, so i am not really sure where it is falling out.

Comment: Which `HandlerMapping` and `HandlerAdapter` are you using? You aren't using the old `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` instead of the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and matching `HandlerMapping`?

Comment: @M.Deinum App does have a AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter registered. The app is little old, So i may not be able to switch to RequestMappingHandlerAdapter directly unfortunately. Is that why it is not happening?

Comment: I suspect so because handing and processing of values considerably changed between the 2 mechanisms. Newer additions don't work for the old `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` only the newer one.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am working on it to see if that is what is the trouble maker.

Comment: @M.Deinum, You are absolutely right. AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter is the trouble maker. Using RequestMappingHandlerAdapter solved the issue.